# Using a DBM RewriteMap to rewrite thousands of legacy URLs

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

Organization I'm working for is implementing a new CMS.  As such, a vast number of URLs (say tens of thousands) will be being rewritten to new ones.  Some of them may be 302'ed to the new URI pattern, like:

```
RewriteRule ^/articles/articlename.html /new/article/taxonomy/and/such.html [R,L]
```

Others, we'll want to pass-through to the CMS backend so that the end-user sees the same URL, though it's served from the new path internally, like

```
RewriteRule ^/articles/article2.html /content/en/new/article/path/article2.html [PT,L]
```

I was planning to put this in a pair of FAT DBM rewritemaps, so as to handle the two types separately, but faster than just putting them in there as thousands of individual rewrite rules.

I'm a unclear though, on how to call these so that mod_rewrite only picks up any URLs that match one of the keys in the DBM file, and then replace it with the value.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteMap 302_rewrites dbm:/etc/httpd/conf/rewritemaps/dbmtest_302.dbm
RewriteRule ^${302_rewrites:$1} ${302_rewrites:$2} [R,L]
```

The above doesn't work.  But am I close?

Answer (score 1):

You can't use use your `RewriteMap` in the left-hand side (the match) of a `RewriteRule`.  Additionally, since no match has occurred at that point, there's nothing in `$1`.  You could specify a default value in the `RewriteRule`, like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(/articles/.*) ${302_rewrites:$1|$1} [R,L]
```

This will look up the request path (`/articles/mumble/...`) in your database, and if nothing is found, it will return the original path.  If not everything starts with `/articles` you can obviously make your match more general:

```
RewriteRule ^(/.*) ...
```